# How are websites requiring authentication made?

Tags: php, javascript, html, authentication

How do websites (such as this one) handle log-ins? The only way I know is to take the username and password using an HTML form and use PHP to check it against a database and if it matches creates a session. In every page that requires a user to be logged in have

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != 'true')
    header( 'Location: login.html' );
?>
<HTML>
...
```

But according to [this page](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html) `<input type="password">` is transferred in clear text so anything using HTML's input is bad. According to the [JavaScript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/loginpass2.shtml) all JavaScript password scripts are insecure. What can one use?

Comment: ["*If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: You really need to do more research. JavaScript is irrelevant here, look in to how `<input type="password">` and server communications work.

Comment: I honestly think people were too harsh here. I don't see what's ambiguous, David answered the question without writing a book, what is the problem?

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad, or rhetorical** and **cannot be reasonably answered in its current form**. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple scenario you outline above is about how it usually works. `<input type="password">` *is* by default sent to the server in plain text, which is why login pages should use HTTPS to encrypt that communication. JavaScript has nothing to do with this.